# php instagram login error

Tags: php, curl

until last week i could log on instagram with this code. But now not working.
Maybe "http://instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax" not working what must i do for work well?

```
<?php

class Instagram {

    public $data;
    public function saveCache($users) {
        $opt_keys = array();
        foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
            $ROOT_PATH[$key] = dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies/". $user["username"];
            if (!(is_dir($ROOT_PATH[$key]))) {
                mkdir($ROOT_PATH[$key]);
            }
            $cookie_filename = $ROOT_PATH[$key] . "/" . $user["username"] . "-cache.txt";
            $this->data[$key] = array("cookie_filename" => $cookie_filename, "state" => "get_cookie", "username" => $user["username"], "password" => $user["password"]);
            $opts[$key] = array("url" => "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login", "cookie_jar" => $cookie_filename);
        }
        multi_curl($opts, function ($que, $key) use ($ROOT_PATH) {

                $content = $que->content;
                $opt_key =& $this->data[$key];
                $username = $opt_key["username"];
                $password = $opt_key["password"];
                $cookie_filename = $opt_key["cookie_filename"];
                $state =& $opt_key["state"];

                switch ($state) {
                    case "get_cookie":
                        if (preg_match("#\"csrf_token\":\"([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}+)\"#siU", $content, $match)) {
                            $csrf_token = array_pop($match);
                            $post_string = array("username" => trim($username), "password" => trim($password));
                            $post_string = http_build_query($post_string, "", "&");
                            $state = "login";
                            return array("url" => "https://instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/", "post" => $post_string, "cookie_jar" => $cookie_filename, "cookie_file" => $cookie_filename, "key" => $key, "http_header" => array("Origin:https://instagram.com", "Referer:https://instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/?targetO1rigin=https%3A%2F%2Finstagram.com", "X-CSRFToken:" . $csrf_token, "X-Instagram-AJAX: 1", "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"));
                        }
                        break;

                    case "login":
                        $json = json_decode($content, false);
                        if (isset($json->authenticated) && $json->authenticated) {
                            echo($username . " giri\xc5\x9f yap\xc4\xb1ld\xc4\xb1<br>");
                            $tokens = $json->authenticated;
                            $dosya_adi = "userler.txt";
                            $dosya = fopen ($dosya_adi , 'a+') or die ("Dosya açılamadı!");
                            fwrite ( $dosya , "$username:$password\n" ) ;
                            fclose ($dosya);

                            $state = "insta_main";
                            return array("url" => "https://instagram.com/web/likes/1009482544587251742/like/", "cookie_file" => $cookie_filename, "key" => $key, "http_header" => array("Referer:https://instagram.com/", "X-CSRFToken:" . @$csrf_token, "X-Instagram-AJAX:1", "X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest"));
                        }
                        echo($username . " giri\xc5\x9f yap\xc4\xb1lamad\xc4\xb1.<br>");
                        @unlink($opt_key["cookie_filename"]);
                        @rmdir($ROOT_PATH[$key]);
                        break;

                    case "insta_main":
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;

                }
            }
, 150);
    }




}


require("Curl.php");
define("ROOT_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));
set_time_limit(0);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", dirname(__FILE__) . "/php-error.log");
$instagram = new Instagram();
if ($_POST) {
    $users = explode("\n", $_POST["users"]);
    $veruser = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $bol = explode(":", $user);
        $veruser[] = array("username" => trim($bol[0]), "password" => trim($bol[1]));
    }
    $instagram->saveCache($veruser);
    exit();
}
echo("<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">\r\n    <textarea name=\"users\" rows=\"20\" cols=\"50\"></textarea>\r\n    <input type=\"submit\">\r\n</form>\r\n");
function delTree($dir) { 
   $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); 
    foreach ($files as $file) { 
      (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? delTree("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file"); 
    } 
    return rmdir($dir); 
  }
```

Comment: remove unnecessary description.

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution, I test it and it works

[Login with Instagram OAuth using PHP.](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/login-with-instagram-php.html)